# Prove that $TQBF^{\exists}_2$ is complete for the class $\Sigma_2$

Tags: complexity-theory

> Prove that $TQBF^{\exists}_2$ is complete for the class $\Sigma_2$.

Where the input for $TQBF^{\exists}_2$ is a totally quantified boolean formula: $\exists_{x_1\in\{T,F\}}\forall_{x_2\in\{T,F\}}\phi(x_1,x_2)$ and it is in the language iff the truth value of the totally quantified expression is True.

My way of thinking was- If I take a language $L\in\Sigma_2$ then there exists a $\mathsf{TM}$ $M(x,y_1,y_2)$ that runs in time $\mathit{poly}(|x|)$ such that $x\in L$ iff $\exists_{y_1}\forall_{y_2}M(x,y_1,y_2)=T$ .
So I can take the computation table of $M$ on $x$ and turn all the local computation blocks into variables $z_i$ and somehow turn it into a formula of $TQBF^{\exists}_2$.
I would appreciate  your help understanding the details.